# Content Page Tool Bar Item Is Missing Upon Navigating using PopUpPage Prism

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm currently facing a problem that when I use

`await _navigationService.PushPopupAsync()`

The tool bar item on the next page where I am going to navigate is missing its like the `PushPopupAsync()` is destroying my next page.

Does somebody encounter this kind of problem?

Comment: The page which does not have the toolbar must be having `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar=false` in the xaml or `SetHasNavigationBar(this, false)` in the xaml.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is no longer supported. That was a deprecated after version 1.

You'll need to be sure that you've registered the PopupNavigationService, and registered your PopupPage's the same as any other page. After that all you need to do is navigate to them the same as you would any other page `NavigationService.NavigateAsync("SomePopupPage")`

See [Repo](https://github.com/dansiegel/Prism.Plugin.Popups) for more info and a full sample.